# Get Data From Contentful with Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, contentful, next.js13

I try to get my first data from contentful cms with next.js 13.

Unfortunately the below code returns always undefined in the console.log(recipes).

I think this code worked in an older version of next.js.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong? The id of the content model is correct.

Best Regards
Carlo

This is the code:

```
import { createClient } from 'contentful'


export async function getStaticProps() {

  const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
  })
  
  const res = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "recipe" }) 

  return {
    props: {
      recipes: res.items,
    }
  }
}

export default function Home({ recipes }) {
  console.log(recipes)
  return (
    <div>
      blabla
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: After a long research i have now this new code for another block with a picture - and it works:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import { createClient } from 'contentful';
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer';
import About from './Ueber/Page';

const { CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID, CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY } = process.env;

async function getBlocks() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/${process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}/entries?access_token=${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY}&content_type=homeBlock`
  );
  return res.json();
}

// Options for rendering rich text
const renderOptions = {
  renderText: text => text.split('\n').flatMap((text, i) => [i > 0 && <br key={`br-${i}`} />, text]),
};

export default async function HomeBlock() {
  const data = await getBlocks();

  const blocks = data.items.map((item) => {
    const blockText = item.fields.blockText;
    const paragraphs = documentToReactComponents(blockText, renderOptions);
    const paragraphsWithLineBreaks = paragraphs.flatMap((paragraph, index) => [
      paragraph,
      index < paragraphs.length - 1 && <br key={`br-${index}`} />,
    ]);

    const blockPic = data.includes.Asset.find((asset) => asset.sys.id === item.fields.blockPic.sys.id);
    const imageUrl = `https:${blockPic.fields.file.url}`;

    return {
      paragraphs: paragraphsWithLineBreaks,
      imageUrl,
    };
  });

  return (
 <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-8 p-8">
      {blocks.map((block, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="text-xl flex items-center justify-center gap-4 w-full mb-8 py-4 px-8"
        >
          <div className="max-w-md" style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>
            {block.paragraphs}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <div className="w-60 flex justify-end">
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <img
              src={blocks[blocks.length - 1]?.imageUrl}
              alt="Block Image"
              className="rounded-full max-h-60"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code also takes over the line breaks from the rich text field but the picture is still not where it should be :). How to make such a workflow clean and clear also for rich text? --> My new code looks to complicated just to fetch a simple text and picture.

I just want my blocks just to look like i did them in contentful without a lot of coding workarounds.

Comment: Hey Carlo, I tried your code and it works well with Pages Route in Next.js 13.  Can it be possible that your component is returned before the data is fetched? I can't think of any other reason that would cause this.

Comment: Hi harshil - thx for testing. I was researching a lot about this topic: 

Something like this works:

async function getBlocks() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/${process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}/entries?access_token=${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY}&content_type=homeBlock`
  );
  return res.json();
}

But i still have problems taking over line breaks from contentful rich text editor. I ended up in a lot of ai code and have a superlong code now just to fetch a simple text and image :(

Comment: .. i think all the old code didnt work because of the new app router?

Comment: Hey Karl, I do believe that it is because of the app router. As mentioned, I tried it with Pages Route, and it is working well for me.

Comment: Jap true i tried it with pages before too - and this worked. I found some workarounds meanwhile also for the app router - but i am still struggeling to find out how to use contentful also "client side" - all .env and imports dont work clientside